# Should my GLSL Shader object/wrapper encapsulate loading/setting a VertexArrayObject?

Tags: opengl, c++, 2d, vao

I am working on a 2D game in C++, with a simple rendering layer over OpenGL.

I have a wrapper for GLSL shaders and shader programs, these wrappers encapsulate shader objects into C++ classes and automatically handle loading/compiling/linking and using shader programs.

VertexArrayObjects, it seems to me, are basically a collection of configuration settings to use with a particular ShaderProgram.

My question is: Should I encapsulate VAO's within my ShaderProgram objects, or within the Sprite objects? Does a VAO change on a per-shader basis or do I need a new VAO for every type of drawable object? If the latter, do I need one VAO to draw all Sprites (each containing 4 vertices, a position/orientation etc), or one VAO per sprite object in the game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you shouldn't attach the VAO to a Shader Program. The VAO has to be linked with a Vertex Buffer, which makes it somewhat not shareable. You can only share it to the same extent you would share a Vertex Buffer. Whereas a Shader Program is highly shareable (you may be able to render all objets with the same program).

The purpose of the VAO is to reduce some API overhead when setting a Vertex Buffer and Vertex Format, so you can think of it as a container for a Vertex Buffer and its state.

It is up to you how you want to lay it out on code, but my suggestion would be having 3 distinct classes: `VertexBuffer`, `VertexFormat` and `VAO`.

Give a unique VAO to each mesh/model and then attach shared VertexBuffers and VertexFormats to them.

Comment: What functionality would we wrap in the VertexFormat?

Comment: The "VertexFormat" in OpenGL is what you pass to the `glVertexAttribPointer ` calls.

Comment: Well, actually. There literally is a vertex format in GL 4.3 (as part of [`ARB_vertex_attrib_binding`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/vertex_attrib_binding.txt)), but I suspect that is not what the OP is asking about. `glVertexAttribPointer (...)` *does* setup the format by its very nature, but it also does some extra things.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman out of curiosity what do you mean by extra things?

Comment: @SamCoulter: Well, it sets up the binding for the vertex buffer in addition to the format. `ARB_vertex_attrib_binding` broke the process that `glVertexAttriPointer (...)` performs into two separate commands for enhanced flexibility.